# Errors when building C++ files in Android NDK project using Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I have been having some real problems hooking up the Android NDK to work within the Eclipse IDE.

Specifically, I have been trying to use the NDK to work with OpenCV, and as such I have downloaded the OpenCV samples, which include a project that does facial recognition on camera frames.

This project, after some time, I have managed to get fully working in Eclipse. The NDK building works, as does the indexer within eclipse. When I change something in the C++ code, it builds it correctly... everything works.

However, then comes my problem: I want to create my own project. To do this I decided it was a good idea firstly to just copy across this sample project as a base, and change it from there. Once I have copied this project, however, the build errors appear - the jni C++ files show loads of errors, and when I make changes they do not build (so I don't think this is just an indexing issue).

Does anyone know of settings that would not be transferred when I copy the project in this way? I have tried comparing all of the settings I have been playing with up to this point to try and get it to build.

I hope this question is not too vague. Let me know if there is any more info I could add, to make it more clear.

The OpenCV samples come with OpenCV4Android, that can be downloaded here: http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: It ***is*** too vague. You copied files from an OpenCV sample: which sample, which files did you copy? Could you build the project after copying, before you started changes? Which errors did you see? Can you use command-line `ndk-build`, or it also failed same way as the build using Eclipse?

Comment: I have been trying to use the 'Face Detection' sample, to test the native building.

I have been using ndk-build, and I think actual building is successful (I can run the program - even after modification), however the highlighting in eclipse still shows a whole load of errors.

Comment: Sorry let me make myself clearer - the actual sample builds, and the highlighting in eclipse works. When I copy the project and reimport it into eclipse, it builds but the highlighting doesn't work.

Comment: So, why do you think it is not the infamous indexer issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **`Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor`**, set `Current toolchain` to **`Android GCC`** and `current builder` to **`Android Builder`**
then `select tools` and replace compiler with **`GCC C++ Compiler`**.

Then you should set Paths to your header files.

[image]
[image]